# Trouble with Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to create a stored procedure which takes 1 parameters. I am getting errors when I save below. Any idea? This code is just a small sample run. The length of the whole code is about 1500 lines. If you can help me I can do a big job. I am trying to create a stored procedure for the first time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OZET IS
  BELGE TYPE;

  SELECT F.HAT,
         (ROUND((ROUND((((1440 - SUM(F.PLNSZ)) - SUM(F.PLNLI)) /
                       (1440 - SUM(F.PLNLI))),
                       2)) * (ROUND(SUM(F.FIILI) /
                                    (1440 - (SUM(F.PLNLI) + SUM(F.PLNSZ))),
                                    2)) *
                (ROUND(((1 - (SUM(F.H1) + SUM(F.H2) + SUM(F.H3) + SUM(F.H4) +
                       SUM(F.H5) + SUM(F.H6) + SUM(F.H7) + SUM(F.H8) +
                       SUM(F.H9) + SUM(F.H10))) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)),
                       2)),
                2)) OEE,
         (ROUND((((1440 - SUM(F.PLNSZ)) - SUM(F.PLNLI)) /
                (1440 - SUM(F.PLNLI))),
                2)) AR,
         (ROUND(SUM(F.FIILI) / (1440 - (SUM(F.PLNLI) + SUM(F.PLNSZ))), 2)) PR,
         (ROUND(((1 - (SUM(F.H1) + SUM(F.H2) + SUM(F.H3) + SUM(F.H4) +
                SUM(F.H5) + SUM(F.H6) + SUM(F.H7) + SUM(F.H8) +
                SUM(F.H9) + SUM(F.H10))) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)),
                2)) QR,
         SUM(F.TOPLAM) ADET,
         SUM(F.D1) D1,
         SUM(F.D2) D2,
         SUM(F.D3) D3,
         SUM(F.D4) D4,
         SUM(F.D5) D5,
         SUM(F.D6) D6,
         SUM(F.D7) D7,
         SUM(F.D8) D8,
         SUM(F.D9) D9,
         SUM(F.D10) D10,
         ((ROUND(((SUM(F.H1) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H2) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H3) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H4) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H5) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H6) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H7) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H8) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H9) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) +
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H10) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2))) HATATOPLAM,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H1) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H1,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H2) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H2,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H3) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H3,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H4) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H4,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H5) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H5,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H6) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H6,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H7) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H7,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H8) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H8,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H9) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H9,
         (ROUND(((SUM(F.H10) * 100) / SUM(F.TOPLAM)), 2)) H10
    FROM E_HDFTKP_FORM_TABLO1 F
   INNER JOIN E_HDFTKP_FORM S
      ON F.FORMID = S.ID
   INNER JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS FD
      ON S.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
   INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS LF
      ON FD.PROCESSID = LF.ID
   INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES FL
      ON LF.FLOWVERSION = FL.VERSION
     AND FL.STATUS = LF.STATUS
     AND FL.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS
   WHERE F.HAT = 'M26'
     AND BELGENO = BELGE
   GROUP BY F.HAT

BEGIN
  BELGE := 0;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
    RAISE;
END OZET;
/
```

Comment: The select statement, which should be ended with a semi-colon , suggest a cursor, ain't it? And the other error should rise due to the assignment of the variable `BELGE` ... Btw, there seems to be no *parameter* to be taken.

Answer (score 2):

Idea? Yes: take some time and read documentation about PL/SQL. In my opinion, you shouldn't be trying to write any program without knowing anything about that language. If you wrote 1500 lines and didn't test it, whoa, you're doing it wrong. Go step-by-step, test frequently, don't go any further before previous step works OK.

---

As of code you posted: it is invalid in quite a few ways.

- procedure with 1 parameter: nope, there are no parameters there
- in PL/SQL, a `SELECT` must have its `INTO`; you don't have it. As this statement returns *many* columns and - possibly - more than a single row, a collection might be a good choice. You'll need a custome-defined type for that

  - alternatively, `SELECT` you posted *might* be a cursor definition; in that case, you'll probably need a loop if you want to work row-by-row
- `belge type` is also wrong; `belge` looks like that "parameter" you mentioned; I presume you want to pass it as an IN parameter to the procedure. If that's so, you'll have to declare it that way
- there are missing semi-colons which terminate statements
- main part of the procedure (between `BEGIN` and `END`) doesn't do anything (apart from initializing belge local variable); what do you plan to do with that `SELECT`?